# Google Maps iOS SDK and storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, storyboard

I was hoping someone could explain how to get started with Google Maps and Xcode storyboards.
I can't find any information about how to actually do it. I just need an example or the steps to take.

There is this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3H8dFG0UCY Google shortcuts video. But I can't see the code in the video.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create in the View in which you want to insert the map a generic UIView, than in the file inspector, give it the custom class "GMSMapView".

Then you can create a IBOutlet to it in the view controller header file and initialize the map..

Comment: I tried that. It worked. Though it wasn't necessary to do the IBOutlet part. I'll experiment some more. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome..I ask you to mark my answer as correct, it would really help me..thanks! :-D

Comment: How can you assign a map ID for Google Cloud map styling? There is an initialiser for GMSMapView to pass a map ID, but no function that I can see to assign an ID for a GMSMapView created with storyboard.